# "View code" context menu item inside Word

Tags: ms-word, vsto

I have a code-backed Word template in which I am customizing numerous things, such as the ribbon, the backstage (the file menu), and the context menus.

Whenever I open the context menu for text, there is a menu item at the top labeled "View Code". It does nothing when selected.

[image: Word content menu item 'View code']

This menu item does not appear for other content types, such as fields or lists. My customization of the text context menu does not include this item.

I found [one other person](http://question.ikende.com/question/363438393635353430) on the internet that had this issue but they were not able to resolve it. I have looked through the [list of control ids](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=6627) looking for this item but was not able to find it.

Where does this come from?

Comment: I suspect that this appears because VSTO controls (at least some of them) in a document's surface have to be hosted within ActiveX controls, and the context menu of an ActieX control in Design mode will have a View Code item in its context menu. Clicking it would normally open the VB(A) Editor to allow you to work with the event code for the control, but I forget OTTOMH whether that is suppressed when you are using VSTO.

Comment: FWIW I see the same entry in a document with no association to VSTO and no customization fo the context menu. I have no idea why the command is there, but it appears to be coming from Word, not your customization. (I'm looking at Word 2010 BTW)

Comment: OK, is having a loaded VSTO addin/template enough to cause this menu item to appear?

Comment: The answer seems to be no. Normal Word 2010 isn't showing it for me. Nor is it showing in a blank document or template project.

Comment: More info on this oddity: starting Word in Safe mode got rid of it - completely (for the moment, anyway). When I started Word again normally it was gone. And no combination of add-ins, Design Mode, VBA Editor, etc. brought it back.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While I still don't know for sure the cause of this issue, I believe it may have come from using the [Custom UI Editor For Microsoft Office](http://openxmldeveloper.org/blog/b/openxmldeveloper/archive/2009/08/06/7293.aspx) at one point in the past. I did find a resolution though.

To find the issue, I removed each part of my project, item-by-item, until I was back to what was essentially a bare project, and the menu item still existed. So, I swapped in a freshly-created *.dotm file, and the menu item disappeared. Then, I dug into the file structure of the original *.dotm and compared it to the fresh one. One of the differences that stuck out was the presence of the file "word/[attachedToolbars.bin](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff531660%28v=office.12%29.aspx)". Despite the documentation I'm still not sure what it's supposed to hold. Anyway, I deleted it by taking the following steps.

- Deleted the word\attachedToolbars.bin file
- Deleted the word\customizations.xml file that references it (nothing else was in it)
- Deleted the word\_rels\customizations.xml.rels file that references it (nothing else was in it)
- Deleted the reference to customizations.xml in word\_rels\document.xml.rels
- Deleted the reference to word/customizations.xml in [Content_Types].xml

This got rid of the menu item. However, several of my customizations were lost (a table style, two building blocks, and the list of quick styles, though the styles themselves were still present). So anyone encountering this will probably be better off just re-creating their customizations.

To try making it appear again, I tried

- Editing the file in the Custom UI Editor again
- Adding my customizations back
- Publishing the template

None worked. But, at least I now have a template with everything I want and nothing I don't.

Comment: Strictly speaking this isn't an answer to 'where does this come from' but I think it's as close as anyone is going to get.